# Increase the output variance of a neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, distribution, variance

I'm currently trying to implement a simple network with the following structure :

input(128) -----> layer 1 (50 neurones) -----> layer 2 (50 neurones) ----> output (1 neurone)

I have very few and sparse data and it seems that my network has a very small output variance (close to the mean of the output distribution).
However i know that my network is twice better that a the one which is always returning the mean of the output distribution.

So the questions are :

- How can i increase the variance of the output and not return always almost the same value ?
- Someone told me to look at Bayesian Network, for which i can set some prior about the distribution... Is it a good idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

PS : And no, i haven't forgotten to normalise my data...

Comment: Even though you have normalized your data: Have you "just" normalized it, or used a `StandardScaler`, which additionally also allows you to scale to unit variance? Also, if you struggle with sparsity, Autoencoder architectures can be quite helpful (i.e. having a layer with very few neurons in between).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you mean try an auto encoder as pretraining before the supervised task ?

Comment: Or alternatively just directly use an Encoder to reduce your data dimensionality, or even add smaller layers in your actual network to "artificially densify" your data. Altough without testing it is hard to tell what would work and what not. I also haven't personally worked with Bayesion Networks, so I cannot say whether they would be more useful.